# Posting JSON data to Web API - where do I even start?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I have zero experience with Web API and JSON.  My requirements are to create a service (I'm using Web API for this) that will accept MIME Encoded JSON data.  The service will take that data, insert it into a database, and return the primary key value back to the client.

My hang-up is being able to know where to even start with this.  A couple of questions that I have are:

1. When the device sends the JSON data, how will the service "accept" it?  Meaning, what's being passed to the service isn't an URL that we commonly see with MVC (/Controller/Action/ID) which then invokes the Action Method.  So, how will the service know what to invoke if I'm passing raw JSON data?
2. How would I test this if I don't have a device that sends the JSON data yet?  Would I manually invoke an AJAX call and call that particular action method and pass in the JSON data that way?

I apologize for the seemingly elementary questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you call a WebAPI-method you still have to specify the endpoint:

Example:

```
PUT /api/people
```

MVC knows from that that it should call the put-method on the PeopleController.

1. You can send raw JSON-data to test it. A good tool for that is HttpFiddler: http://fiddler2.com/

As for where to start, try to create a basic WebAPI-project with visual studio, it will include some samples and you can get going from that. If you run into wall, you can come back here